# Display form input in same page

Tags: javascript

I am working on a simple form demo and i would like the input to display in a  below the form.  Currently i have it populating in the console. How do i may it display in the div when i click the submit button?
My code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.submitForm').on('click',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();     

        $('#firstName').val();
        $('#lastName').val();
        $('#phoneNumber').val();
        $('#address').val();    

        console.log($('#firstName').val());
        console.log($('#lastName').val());
        console.log($('#phoneNumber').val());
        console.log($('#address').val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're currently not putting the values anywhere but into the console.log.

I would expect to see something like (let's call your div you want the values to go to, "output"):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.submitForm').on('click',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        // Borrowing from another response, this is better
        // Putting these in variables protects you from 
        // 1) accidentally modifying your form values
        // 2) invalid input, if you add some basic checks, like
        //    testing to see if the length is > 0, doesn't contain
        //    bad characters, etc.
        var firstName = $('#firstName').val(),
            lastName  = $('#lastName').val(),
            phone     = $('#phoneNumber').val(),
            address   = $('#address').val();

        // get a reference to the div you want to populate
        var $out = $("#output");

        // This is a better way of dealing with this
        // because every call to .append() forces DOM
        // reparsing, and if you do this too often, it can cause
        // browser slowness. Better to put together one string
        // and add it all at once.
        $out.html("<p>" + firstName + "</p>" + 
                  "<p>" + $('#lastName').val() + "</p>" +
                  "<p>" + $('#phoneNumber').val() + "</p>" + 
                  "<p>" + $('#address').val() + "</p>");                    
    });
});
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! I understand it's not the most efficient way but it's my 2nd day working with javascript so its a start!

Comment: I made some modifications based on jbabey's code, as well, with some explanation of the differences. Keep plugging away, there's a lot you can do with Javascript, and it can be kind of fun when it's not got you pulling out hair! :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation mori. Inside of the <div> i had some text in a <p>. When I click the submit button, the input displays in the <div> but replaces/removes the <P> text, unlike that code before that kept the <P>. any idea why that is happening?

Comment: Ah, in that case, you'll want to use something like $out.append() instead of $out.html() ... .html() replaces all the nodes within it with the new content. .append() adds the nodes to whatever content is already inside it.

Comment: Meta-question: is it rude to ask for my answer to be chosen if it's solving the OP's problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.submitForm').on('click',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();                         
        //$('#firstName').val();
        //$('#lastName').val();
        //$('#phoneNumber').val();
        //$('#address').val();   

        var htmlContent = $('#firstName').val() + '<br />' + $('#lastName').val() + '<br />' + $('#phoneNumber').val() + '<br />' + $('#address').val();

        $('#ID_OF_YOUR_DIV_HERE').html(htmlContent);
    }); 
});
```

Maybe this is what you're after??

Comment: $('#firstName').val();
        $('#lastName').val();
        $('#phoneNumber').val();
        $('#address').val();    will do nothing or in the worst case remove the values

Comment: I'm more then fully aware haha. I was using the OP's code as it is to not confused them, but only show them the difference. They could of written them out for later use also.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.submitForm').on('click',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();     
        $(this).after('<div>First name: '+$('#firstName').val()+'<br>'+
        'Last name: '+$('#lastName').val()+
        ' .... ');

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the four lines where you read the `.val()` but don't do anything with it are essentially wasted cycles, you probably meant to store them in variables:

```
var firstName = $('#firstName').val();
var lastName = $('#lastName').val();
var phoneNumber = $('#phoneNumber').val();
var address = $('#address').val();
```

To show them in some other element, use the setter version of `.val()` for input types, or `.text()` if it's a display type (div, span, etc):

```
$('#someOtherElement').text(firstName + '\n' + 
    lastName + '\n' 
    phoneNumber + '\n' 
    address);
```

Comment: Those newlines will turn into spaces. You should use `.html()` and `<br>` tags to create line breaks. Or more likely, each value should be put in a different element.

Answer (score -1):

You can add it to a div you want with .append(), for example

```
$("#divYouWantToAddTo").append($('#firstName'));
```

Comment: This will append the #firstname NODE to the div, not the node's value. Closer would be `$("#divYouWantToAddTo").append($('#firstName').val());`

Answer (score -1):

I don't know where to start... What is all that `$('#....').val()` in the middle there, wasting time only to throw away the result..?

What is wrong with `document.getElementById('...').value` instead of wasting time creating an entire jQuery object just to access something trivial?

Adding text to a node is as simple as `container.appendChild(document.createTextNode(sometext));` - and if you want to have newlines between them you can also do `container.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));`.

There is no need for jQuery here at all...

Comment: As he's already using jQuery for event handling, and he's asking with jQuery code, doesn't he deserve to understand how to fix it using jQuery?

Comment: 2nd day with javascript, be nice!

Comment: @Anthony I'm afraid that makes it worse. You should learn vanilla JavaScript first, then upgrade to jQuery if you feel it is necessary. IF you had done that, I'm fairly sure you wouldn't be asking how to do something so trivial...